# Adding raster TIFF image directly on the map using OpenLayers without using GeoServer?

Tags: raster, openlayers, javascript

I want to know how to add an raster tif image onto map using OpenLayers

```
var imgextent = [extent array];

                         var geoRasterMap = new ol.layer.Image({
                             //  extent: bbox,
                             source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                                 ratio: 1,
                                 
                                 url: 'http://url/A.tif',
                                 extent: imgextent

                                 //params: {
                                 //    'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
                                 //    'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                                 //    STYLES: '',
                                 //    LAYERS: 'cite:' + zname,
                                 //}
                             }),
                             zIndex: 0

                         });

                         map.addLayer(geoRasterMap);
```

This is error I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2')
> at ye (extent.js:620:27)
> at e.getImageInternal (ImageStatic.js:100:13)
> at e.getImage (Image.js:166:25)
> at e.prepareFrame (ImageLayer.js:78:41)
> at e.render (Layer.js:213:27)
> at e.renderFrame (Composite.js:113:33)
> at e.renderFrame_ (PluggableMap.js:1150:24)
> at e. (PluggableMap.js:179:18)

Comment: Is it a simple tif image or a GeoTIFF?

Comment: It is tif image

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the propery name should be `imageExtent` (not `extent`).

However unless you are using a browser such as Internet Explorer which supports tiff format directly you will need to use custom load function with a tiff decoder such as tiff.js to load the image

```
        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
          url: 'http://url/A.tif',
          imageExtent: extent,
          imageLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            xhr.open('GET', src);
            xhr.onload = function (e) {
              var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: xhr.response});
              var canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
              image.getImage().src = canvas.toDataURL();
            };
            xhr.send();
          }
        })
```

Working example: https://jsbin.com/vudizuqodu/1/edit?html,output